# xpages mail nsf in browser

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to pass a field value from a application to my own mail database opened in browser.

I got the entire url ( my first reaction: wow, so long )

```
https://server/MyName.nsf/($Inbox)/$new/?EditDocument&Form=h_PageUI&PresetFields=h_EditAction;h_New,s_NotesForm;Memo,s_ParentContentId;($Inbox)1,s_ViewName;(%24Inbox),s_InheritAttachment;false,s_SortOrder;1,s_SortColumnPN;$70&ui=portal
```

How can I refer easily to the recipient field ? ( `To:` field ) from the mail database ?

I want to use a sessionScope which picks the desired value and then pass it to the above field.

I did for the above requirement in a lotus notes application using lotusScript something like this:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    // soome declarations
    Set db=s.CurrentDatabase
    Dim dcc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Set dcc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
    Dim item As NotesItem
    Set doc = dcc.GetFirstDocument
'   em$=doc.nms_Email(0)

    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        If doc.HasItem ("nms_Email") Then 
            Set item=doc.GetFirstItem("nms_Email")
        Else
            If doc.HasItem ("txt_Email") Then 
                Set item=doc.GetFirstItem("txt_Email")
            Else
                Messagebox "No value for the field!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        Forall e In item.values
            If Len(e) > 2 Then  em$=em$+e+"; "  
        End Forall
        Set doc=dcc.GetNextDocument(doc)
    Wend
    If em$=";" Then Exit Sub
    test$=Strleftback(em$, ";")
    var=Evaluate({@Explode("} & test$ & {"; ";")})
    var2=Evaluate("@MailDbName")
    mdb$=var2(1)
    msv$ =var2(0)
    Set dbm=s.GetDatabase(msv$, mdb$, False)
    Set docW = dbm.CreateDocument
    docW.form = "Memo"
    docW.SendTo=var
    Set uidoc = w.EditDocument(True,docW)

End Sub
```

But how can I do the same thing in xpages?

Comment: Most likely not possible unless you add logic to your mail template to read paramaters from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

iNotes is not an XPages application (which is why the URL is so long).

You can create a new email with the relevant value in the "to" field using a `mailto:` link. This is standard web development functionality, not proprietary to XPages or Domino, so there are plenty of pages explaining the functionality. That functionality creates a new mail using whatever is the default mail program for the user's computer. I'm not sure how that works with iNotes though.

Alternatively, iNotes documentation may tell you what you need to add into the URL to set the "to" field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to generate a URL that composes a new E-mail on the iNotes even it has not been configured as the default E-mail client.

Short way to that, with a hacky method, adding `SendTo` to the `PresetFields` parameter in the URL.

Here is the URL you have provided:

```
https://server/MyName.nsf/($Inbox)/$new/?EditDocument&Form=h_PageUI&PresetFields=h_EditAction;h_New,s_NotesForm;Memo,s_ParentContentId;($Inbox)1,s_ViewName;(%24Inbox),s_InheritAttachment;false,s_SortOrder;1,s_SortColumnPN;$70&ui=portal
```

Will be modified as:

```
...&PresetFields=...othervalues...,SendTo;someEmailAddress&ui=portal
```

Instead of usual query strings, iNotes will get `Name1;Value1,Name1;Value1` format for this parameter. So,

`SendTo;name@domain.com` for single e-mail address.

`SendTo;name@domain.com%2Canother@domain.com` for multiple (%2c is for comma. Usual comma is to separate name-value sets).

`SendTo;name@domain.com,CopyTo;another@domain.com,Subject;Test,Body;Test` with other options.

Of course, query string is a limiting factor. You can't have too many values.

The alternative has been explained by Stephan: To create a document in the mail database and use:

```
https://server/mail/myname.nsf/0/unid?EditDocument
```

Mail database will default to iNotes in such case. However, in this scenario, you should save the document into the mail database.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer is one approach. The other would be to do the same as you did in the LotusScript. Create a document in the mail file, save it (as Draft) and then use the URL to open it. You can figure out the needed URL using the developer tools opening a manually created draft

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on `mailto:` protocol. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) you can use it with coma separated list of addresses.

To handle `mailto:` urls by iNotes you need to go to iNotes preferences, or to use this little hack: https://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/tomsparrow/entry/inotes-mailto.

All you need to do in your XPages code is a correct `mailto:` link and let user to click it.